# Replace a 3 parameter list-comprehension by using map, concat

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, translate, higher-order-functions, map-function

I have some understanding of list comprehension. I understand that the expression:

```
[x * x | x <- [1..10]]
should output [1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100]
```

and that the effect of that expression is the same as:

```
map power [1..10]
power x = x * x
```

Now, I have to find out the other method (just like the above) for the following function:

```
[(x,y+z) | x <- [1..10], y <- [1..x], z <- [1..y]]
```

I can't figure it out by myself without errors, please help me

Answer (score 8):

The [Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#list-comprehensions) tells us how to translate list comprehensions:

> ```
> [ e | True ]         = [e]
> [ e | q ]            = [ e | q, True ]
> [ e | b, Q ]         = if b then [ e | Q ] else []
> [ e | p <- l, Q ]    = let ok p = [ e | Q ]
>                            ok _ = []
>                        in concatMap ok l
> [ e | let decls, Q ] = let decls in [ e | Q ]
> ```

Since your list comprehension only uses irrefutable patterns (that is, patterns that never fail), the fourth clause above simplifies somewhat:

```
[ e | p <- l, Q ]    = concatMap (\p -> [ e | Q ]) l
```

I'll use this version for concision, but a true derivation should use the definition from the Report. (Homework: try the real translation, and check that you get the "same thing" in the end.) Let's try it, shall we?

```
  [(x,y+z) | x <- [1..10], y <- [1..x], z <- [1..y]]
= concatMap (\x -> [(x,y+z) | y <- [1..x], z <- [1..y]] [1..10]
= concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\y -> [(x,y+z) | z <- [1..y]]) [1..x]) [1..10]
= concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\y -> [(x,y+z) | z <- [1..y], True]) [1..x]) [1..10]
= concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\y -> concatMap (\z -> [(x,y+z) | True]) [1..y]) [1..x]) [1..10]
= concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\y -> concatMap (\z -> [(x,y+z)]) [1..y]) [1..x]) [1..10]
```

And we're finally at a version that has no list comprehensions.

If you're comfortable with monads, then you can also gain insight into the behavior of this expression by observing that `concatMap` is a flipped version of the list's `(>>=)` function; moreover, `[e]` is like the list's `return e`. So, rewriting with monad operators:

```
= [1..10] >>= \x ->
  [1..x]  >>= \y ->
  [1..y]  >>= \z ->
  return (x,y+z)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
[(x,y+z) | x <- [1..10], y <- [1..x], z <- [1..y]]
```

is the same as

```
concatMap
    (\x -> [(x,y+z) | y <- [1..x], z <- [1..y]])
    [1..10]
```

You can extract the `y` and `z` variables out of the list comprehension similarly. (But you must do it in order from left to right: so `y` next and `z` last.)

`concatMap` is a function defined in the Prelude:

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
concatMap f = concat . map f
```

Comment: You can then go and repeat this for y and z.

Answer (score 3):

You can transform this into `do`-notation:

```
foo = do x <- [1..10]
         y <- [1..x]
         z <- [1..y]
         return (x, y+z)
```

This works because list is a monad. The `do`-notation itself is just syntactic sugar for a monadic calculation. Following the desugaring rules (described [here](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monads.html) under "Desugaring of do blocks") you end up with:

```
[1..10] >>= (\x -> [1..x] >>= (\y -> [1..y] >>= (\z -> [(x,y+z)])))
```

The operator `>>=` is defined in `Control.Monad`, and is equivalent to a `concatMap` with flipped arguments for lists. `return t` is just `[t]` in case of lists.